# Updating PostGIS on Linux

Tags: postgis, postgresql, linux

I have **POSTGIS="2.4.3 r16312"** on my linux server and I need to upgrade it to **POSTGIS="2.4.4 r16526"** or any newer version.
I use the following:

```
ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE;
```

but it gives me the apparante message:

```
version "2.4.3" of extension "postgis" is already installed
```

Would you plesae let me know if how to upgrade the PostGIS version?

Comment: How did you install the new PostGIS version?

Comment: $ sudo apt-get install postgis

Comment: Which version did you install (what is the output of `apt list postgis`)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to also include the version number using the `TO 'x.x.x'`

Where `'x.x.x'` is the new version. Note the `'` (single quotes) are required as it's a string being used.

From the [PostgreSQL ALTER EXTENSION documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterextension.html):

> ALTER EXTENSION extension_name UPDATE [ TO new_version ]

Comment: it gives a new error that ** extension "postgis" has no update path from version "2.4.3" to version "2.4.4"**. I tried to "2.4.4 r16526" and same message. I know this version exists because that is what I have installed on windows.

Comment: its having trouble finding the update script. there is a SQL file that that command calls for one postgis version to another.